# HttpClient PostAsync posting null content

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, asp.net-core-webapi

I have one api calling another.

and here is my code which seems to cause `ModelState.IsValid = false` on the other side of world.

```
var baseUri = new Uri("http://localhost:5001/"):
_httpClient.BaseAdress = baseUri;
var data = new StringContent(content: model.Tostring(),
             encoding: Encoding.UTF8, 
             mediaType: "application/json");

var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("api/product", data);
```

watching `Post([FromBody]Product product)` on the api being called I just see `product=null`.

changing to `Post([FromBody]object product)` also shows `null`.

calling the api from `Postman` works perfectly fine. which localize my problem to `PostAsync`. what's going on with my `PostAsync`?

**Edit**:

I know people might suggest `PostAsJsonAsync`, but I'll try it only after I know what's the problem with `PostAsync`. :(

Comment: Are you sure that `model.ToString()` produces proper JSON? And even if it is, you'd better at least use a separate method like `ToJsonString` or even don't put the serialization code inside that class at all.

Comment: In any case without [MCVE] we can't help you much.

Comment: spot on @EugenePodskal. `model.ToString()` was not doing what I thought it's doing. changing to `content: JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model)` works. is that a way to go?

Comment: That should work assuming that endpoint uses compatible model class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated in the comments the `model` was not being converted to JSON when you called `model.ToString`. You eventually figured out that you can use Json.Net to serialize the model to JSON with `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model)`. This will work for serializing the model to JSON.

You could go one step further and create an extension method to perform that functionality for you

```
public class JSONStringExtension {
    public static string ToJsonString(this object model) {
        if(model is string) throw new ArgumentException("mode should not be a string");
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
    }
}
```

This will now allow you to call the method on your model and covert it to JSON in your code.

```
var baseUri = new Uri("http://localhost:5001/"):
_httpClient.BaseAdress = baseUri;
var data = new StringContent(content: model.ToJsonString(), //<--Extension method here
             encoding: Encoding.UTF8, 
             mediaType: "application/json");

var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("api/product", data);
```

The `PostAsJsonAsync` extension method that is frequently used basically performs the same thing you eventually realized by abstracting the JSON serialization step for you. internally it is calling the same `PostAsync` method.

which would look something a little like this

```
public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsJsonAsync(this HttpClient httpClient, string url, object content) {
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content)
    var data = new StringContent(content: json,
                 encoding: Encoding.UTF8, 
                 mediaType: "application/json");
     return httpClient.PostAsync(url, data);
}
```