# HttpClient returning Bad Request while Postman is working fine

Tags: c#, post, dotnet-httpclient

I've seen a pretty similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41660792/httpclient-postasync-posting-null-content) ("httpclient-postasync-posting-null-content"). In my case I make an instance of `HttpClient` in the constructor :

```
_client = new HttpClient();
```

And later on in one of my methods I'm doing this:

```
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var content = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

string targetUrl = //the url
var httpResponse = await _client.PostAsync(targetUrl,content);
```

So basically that's it. One of the problem is that currently as the request is not working if I leave this row like this:

```
var httpResponse = await _client.PostAsync(targetUrl,content);
```

It actually hangs forever. So for the sake of finding out what is happening I've made this change:

```
var httpResponse = _client.PostAsync(targetUrl, content).Result;
```

which actuaylly returns result but it's `Bad Request`. However the very same request executed from Postman is working just fine.

Also form the question that I've linked above I'm starting to get a feeling that this probably is somehow related to the `string` type and some specific cases when you try to send a `string` in a `POST` request. Friday I think I had a similar issue when I tried to send some simple string like `"23423-32432-sfg-43324"` with `RestSharp` and again, it was not working but the `Postman` was doing just fine.

My assumption is that `Postman` makes some modifications on the `string` before actually posting it, but anyways. Can someone help me here and eventually provide explanation why this happens - the same request is working from `Postman` but failing in the code?

**EDIT**

Adding this line fix it:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

Not sure if this is something specific or a more common problem. May leave it just in case someone else have the same problem.

Comment: You can use Fiddler to capture the HTTP requests and understand what Postman is doing differently

Comment: @KevinGosse I did that and was able to see one difference, however it seems that my knowledge fails me since I don't know what `Postman` is doing behind the scenes and more importantly - how can I do the same from the code.

Comment: Well... what was the one difference?  Thats kinda the most relevant part.

Comment: Well it turns out it was a issue with the `SecurityProtocol`.

Comment: @Leron Out of curiosity, does your app sets Switch.System.Net.DontEnableSchUseStrongCrypto (through code or app.config) to true anywhere?

Comment: @tpeczek No. Or at least I can't find such a place. Out of curiosity, why do you ask? :)

Comment: @Leron It globally affects System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol, but I'm guessing simply the machine is missing some patch or something which causes the value to be different than latest default :)

Comment: @tpeczek I see. Yes, I think the latter is the case here.